# how to use switch inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I have a simple function here :

```
var getlanguageByState = (state) => {
    switch (state){
        case 'FRANCE':
           return 'french';
            break;
        default :
           return 'english';
            break;
    } 
}
```

when I call this function I expect this output like this

```
var result = getlanguageByState ('FRANCE') // french
```

but I'm getting undefined as output..

Comment: It is working properly.

Comment: Your code looks working, only `break` can be deleted, because in front of him `return`

Comment: go for https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals

Comment: okay it is giving undefined in chrome console but in my application it is working.

Comment: working fine. don't see any error

Comment: @Mar1009 What do you type in your console? If you type `var result = getlanguageByState ('FRANCE')` then it will assign `"french"` to `result`, but it wont log anything. If you type `getlanguageByState ('FRANCE')` it should log it fine because it will show the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

```
const getlanguageByState = (state) => {
   let language = null;
    switch (state){
        case 'FRANCE':
          language =  'french';
            break;
        default :
           language = 'english';
            break;
    } 
    return language;
}
const result = getlanguageByState('FRANCE') // this will give you correct output
```